# Loop through mysql table to find a missing day in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am uploading csv files into a mysql table.

```
time_stamp,"Phase 1","Phase 2","Phase 3",Total
2014-07-09 07:59:21,8345,8665,5461,22471
2014-07-09 08:59:21,8345,8665,5461,22471
2014-07-10 07:59:57,9349,9750,6550,25649
```

I want to run a loop that will check if timestamp exists between two time periods say 7:59:59 and 8:59:59, it should append the value of the previous timestamp into the table namely

```
2014-07-09 08:29:21,8345,8665,5461,22471
```

Comment: Might there be a gap of more than a day? I ask because if gaps are always guaranteed to be just one day you may be able to get away without using a "dates table" but otherwise I think you would need such a table.

Comment: There will be gaps of just a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: solution for a gap of 30 minutes:

```
select timestampadd(minute, 30, x.time_stamp) as time_stamp,
       x.phase_1,
       x.phase_2,
       x.phase_3,
       x.total
  from tbl x
 cross join tbl y
 where y.time_stamp =
       (select max(z.time_stamp)
          from tbl z
         where timestampdiff(minute, z.time_stamp, x.time_stamp) < 30)
   and timestampdiff(minute, y.time_stamp, x.time_stamp) not between 0 and
       29.99
   and y.time_stamp < (select max(time_stamp) from tbl)
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51d84/3/0

Solution for a gap of 1 day:

```
insert into tbl
select timestampadd(day, 1, x.time_stamp) as time_stamp,
       x.phase_1,
       x.phase_2,
       x.phase_3,
       x.total
  from tbl x
 cross join tbl y
 where y.time_stamp =
       (select max(z.time_stamp)
          from tbl z
         where cast(z.time_stamp as date) < cast(x.time_stamp as date))
   and cast(y.time_stamp as date) < cast(x.time_stamp as date)
   and cast(timestampadd(day, 1, x.time_stamp) as date) not in
       (select cast(time_stamp as date) from tbl);
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab1c3/2/0

(I added some additional sample data for illustrative purposes)

Comment: My problem got a lot more complicated than that but thanks for this, i  can build up on this.

Comment: No problem, glad it gives you a start

Comment: Will this work if i want to query between 30 minutes ? @Brian DeMilia

Comment: @Bazinga777 how do you mean? If there is a day without a timestamp the above query will select a row with a timestamp 24 hours after the last timestamp of the previos day, with all values in the other columns equal to that previous record. That's all it does

Comment: i changed my question now. Sorry your code worked fine but my problem kind of changed.

Comment: @Bazinga777 I would just create a new question, it's a very different problem

Comment: Instead of a day, it is happening over every 30 minutes

Comment: But would a gap of 2 hours have to be filled in with 4 rows? Or do you never have a gap over 30 minutes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58556/discussion-between-bazinga777-and-brian-demilia).